# Difference between typeof(/\s/) and $.type(/\s/)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why it's throwing message `object` when I try:

```js
alert(typeof(/\s/))
```

To check again, I've made a change:

```js
alert($.type(/\s/))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

We've got `regexp` now.

So, my question: why is `typeof(/\s/)` an `object` instead of `string` or `regexp` in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression is an "object" because it’s an object, just like Date, etc.
A regular expression is an object that describes a pattern of characters.

If you use `typeof` with an `object`, you get `"object"`

Some other examples:

```
typeof []; // "object"
typeof null; // "object"
typeof /regex/ // "object"
typeof new String(""); // "object"
```

With `$.type`

If the argument is either a primitive value or an instance of a standard built-in ECMAScript object, the `[[Class]]` internal property is used to determine the type.

Example:

```
jQuery.type( /test/ ) === "regexp"
```

**[Documentation on $.type](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/)**

Comment: You mean: `Don't use typeof to check the type of any variable because it's not correct exactly`, don't you?

Comment: @HappyCoding  What i mean is that if you are comparing like a string and want to check if its a regular expression then use `$.type` . obviously `typeof` can be used with other things. Check for their usage and use the one that fits your needs

Comment: Many thanks! You can edit the link `$.type` instead of `$.test` :)

Comment: @HappyCoding thanks. that was a typo. Anyways happy to help :)